# Difference between GWT style unit PC and PCT

Tags: gwt

I am working in GWT. My UI elements gets the needed size when I use PC. But it is ignoring the setSize() when i use PCT. What is the difference between PC and PCT in GWT styling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For styling GWT uses CSS, which offers different measurement units. 
These units are represented in GWT  in the enum `Unit`.
`Unit.PC` stands for pica and `Unit.PCT` for percentage.
Percentage is a relative unit while pica is a absolute one.
For more information read [this article](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html) about units in CSS.

Comment: In addition, for a short explanation with simple examples, have a look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp).

Comment: thanq so much :) both of you